# Script to get the procedure and schema name in azure data warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, data-warehouse

I need a script which would print the procedure names and it's schema names in `data warehouse`.
For example: If i have a stored procedure named as `Stats.CountEmployees`
then I want a script which would print

```
ProcedureName  | SchemaName
------------------------------
CountEmployees | Stats
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `sp_stored_procedures`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-stored-procedures-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following query to get that info:

```
SELECT
            s.name as schemaName, p.name AS ProcName
        FROM sys.procedures AS p
        inner join sys.schemas s on p.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

Thanks